# How to get selinux audit files on ubuntu?

Tags: selinux

I am trying to configure selinux on ubuntu 20.04. I've used selinux on CentOS for some years. Im new to ubuntu.
I installed with `apt install policycoreutils selinux-utils selinux-basics`, then `apt install setools setools-gui`

I set to permissive, and rebooted several times. But the /var/log/audit directory is not created, and no audit.log file is created anywhere. There are selinux messages in kern.log. I can use audit2why and audit2allow -i /var/log/kern.org to see what would be denied. But the audit files are used by many scripts and tools.

What can I to to get selinux to write the audit files on ubuntu?

Comment: I tried adding "selinux=1 audit=1 enforcing=0" to the linux command line in grub, that did not work, but now I get "kauditd hold queue overflow" messages :/

Comment: I installed auditd, and kept the kernel options above. So far this seems to be what I wanted.